# Can a premise imply contradictory statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, examples-counterexamples, equivalence-relations, predicate-logic

Can a premise imply contradictory statements? Can two contradictory premises imply the same conclusion? Determine the answers to these questions by doing the following.

1. Prove or disprove: the following is a contradiction $(p\rightarrow q)\land(p\rightarrow\neg q)$
2. Prove or disprove: the following is a contradiction $(p\rightarrow q)\land(\neg p\rightarrow q)$

I'm assuming that I can prove these to be true, because the premise of an implication and its conclusion do not have to be related in any fashion, but I still don't understand how to answer these questions.

---

### Question

- Where should I start to better understand this concept of contradiction?

Comment: What happens if $p$ is false in the first statement?

Comment: There is no reason (or even option) to use $\forall$ and $\exists$ for pure predicate calculus

Comment: What do you mean with "contradiction" in case of a formula ? In classical propositional logic a *contradiction* is the negation of a *tautology*, i.e.a formula that results identically $F$ in the truth-tale. In this sense, neither of the above formulae are *contradictions*. If you can use truth-tables, you can check that the first is equivalent to $\lnot p$ and the second is equivalent to $q$.

Answer (score 3):

"Can a premise imply contradictory statements?"

A *false* premise implies *anything*.

"Can two contradictory premises imply the same conclusion?"

*Anything* implies a *true* conclusion.

(1) and (2): truth tables are allowed?

Comment: Ya I could use a truth table to show the reasoning

Answer (score 1):

You could make a truth table. It's not difficult for just two variables.

But to get some intuitive notion for their satisfiability, you can see that the first statement is the entire premise behind proof by contradiction.

For the second statement, you can notice that if a tautology (such as $p\vee\neg p$) implies a statement $q$, then $q$ must be true. This should help you see that the second is satisfiable.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, assuming you are using natural deduction, not truth tables:

In (1), what do you obtain if you assume $p$ is **true**?

In (2), either $p$ is **true** or  $p$ is **false** by the law of the excluded middle. What do you obtain in either case?